# Issue after upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, apt

I recently migrated from Ubuntu 12.04LTS to 14.04 LTS .I had issues with my 12.04 so I did a factory restore and then upgraded to 14.04.My system is upgraded to 14.04 with no issues but The first thing I see is after restarting a pop up comes system problem detected.If I cancel it I don't see any issues,however the real problem is when I try to install nodejs using the below link---

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
```

then I see some weird erros---------

```
Fetched 23.7 MB in 23s (1,028 kB/s)                                            
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I did try with below solution 
`sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`
but it again gives this error
`rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/apt/lists/partial’: Is a directory`

Please help me on this as I am struggling with this.

Comment: First make sure you have backed up all personal files that you cannot afford to lose. Then I would suggest that (instead of making a factory restore of 12.04 LTS and upgrading it to 14.04 LTS) you should install 14.04 LTS or 16.04 LTS or 18.04 LTS directly, the newer the better, as long as it works with your computer hardware. After the installation you can copy your personal files into the new system and install whatever program packages that you need. This is often the easiest and fastest way.

Comment: I have a back up of all my folders and personal files.So as you said to try directly installing 14.04 LTS or 16.04 LTS. I will try with that.

Comment: After doing a full installation of 18.04 LTS directly by getting an ISO image and installing  it, worked.My system is up and running.Thanks a lot for the suggestion.It really helped .But only thing it is not able to detect an external hard disc.Do I need to install any driver for this.

Comment: Congratulations to a successful installation :-) Please create another question about detecting the external hard disk drive. Describe as much as possible about the external drive, particularly what file systems there are, and if (and how) it was detected by the old system (12.04 LTS).

Comment: Seems like it got detected in another USB port but not on another one on the same machine.